# tagBitmap @ DELPHI ??? What type?

Tags: delphi

I get an error :

> [DCC Error] Unit_TProcessClass.pas(334): E2010 Incompatible Type: 'TBitmap' and 'tagBITMAP'

the class is defined as

```
TMyClass = Class 
private
  MyBMP : TBitmap;
  property aBMP : TBitmap read MyBMP write MyBMP;
```

and the code goes like

```
processABitmap(aMyClass.aBMP) ;  -> here is the compile error !!!
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that there are two types named `TBitmap` in the VCL. One defined in the `Windows` unit and one defined in `Graphics` unit. Clearly you are passing `Windows.TBitmap` to a function expecting `Graphics.TBitmap`, or vice versa.

You almost certainly don't want to have anything to do with `Windows.TBitmap`. So the solution is to make sure that all of your units list the `Graphics` unit **after** the `Windows` unit in the uses clause. This will have the effect of hiding `Windows.TBitmap`.

My psychic debugging suggests that the unit in which `TMyClass` is declared either does not list `Graphics` at all in its `uses` clause, or it lists `Graphics` before `Windows`.

Finally, how would you go about working out something like this yourself? Well, try pressing CTRL+click on the `TBitmap` referenced in `TMyClass`. I'm confident that they will take you to the `TBitmap` declared in `Windows`. That should be enough for you to work out that it's not the type that you meant when you wrote `TBitmap`.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that you confuse `Windows.TBitmap` (aka [`tagBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183371%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), a record describing a bitmap in the sense of the Windows API) with [`Graphics.TBitmap`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap), the VCL bitmap class.

So, you either want

```
var
  b: Windows.TBitmap;
```

or (much more likely)

```
var
  b: Graphics.TBitmap;
```

If you omit the unit, then the last-referenced unit will be used. For instance, if your `uses` clause looks like

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;
```

then `TBitmap` means `Graphics.TBitmap`, and this is what you usually want.

So the solution to your problem either is that you need to add `Graphics` to some `uses` clause, or that you need to make sure that `Graphics` is listed *after* `Windows` in the list.

Comment: In fact, I always make sure `Windows` is the first unit in my uses clause - always. It's naturally the first thing I do with every new unit.